# Pandas: Count the first consecutive True values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to implement a function that identifies the *first consecutive* occurrences in a Pandas `Series`, which has already been masked with the condition I wanted: (e.g.)

`[True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True]`

I want the above input to give the result of `3`, i.e., there are 3 `True` occurrences in a row from the beginning of the series.

I am aware that a big `for` loop would do the work, but are there any vectorized / Pandas-centric way to go around it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What if the series starts with a False, do you want zero or the len of the first consecutive True values?

Comment: Do you only count consecutive Trues?

Comment: Due to mine and @Divakar's extracurricular optimization, you now have a blazingly fast solution.  Have fun!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Question:

*Find the count of the first consecutive `True`s*
Consider `a`

```
a = np.array([True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True])
```

**Answer 1**
`numpy`: Use `np.logical_and.accumulate` on the negation of `a` and take the negation of that to make a mask that eliminates the first series of `False`s if they should exist.  Then append a `False` at the end to ensure we have a non `True` min.  Finally, use `np.argmin` to locate the first minimum value.  If it's found a position `3`, that will indicate `3` `True` values before it.

```
np.argmin(np.append(a[~np.logical_and.accumulate(~a)], False))

3
```

---

**Answer 2**
*`numba.njit`*

I'd like to use `numba` so I can loop and make sure I get to short circuit when we want/need to.  This is a problem that is sure to be answered early in the array.  There isn't need to evaluate things along the entire array for no reason.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def first_true(a):
    true_started = False
    c = 0
    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        if true_started and not j:
            return c
        else:
            c += j
            true_started = true_started or j
    return c

first_true(a)

3
```

---

**Answer 3**
`numpy` smarter use of `argmin` and `argmax`.  I surround `a` with `False` then use `argmax` to find the first `True` then from that point on, use `argmin` to find the first `False` after that.
**Note:** @Divakar made an improvement on this answer that eliminates the use of `np.concatenate` and uses `if/then/else` instead. That cut this already very fast solution by a factor of `3`!

```
def first_true2(a):
    a = np.concatenate([[False], a, [False]])
    return np.argmin(a[np.argmax(a):])

first_true2(a)

3
```

---

How fast are these answers?
[**See @Divakar's Answer for source code of other functions being timed**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44611917/2336654)

```
%timeit first_true(a)
%timeit np.argmin(np.append(a[~np.logical_and.accumulate(~a)], False))
%timeit np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,a,0])))[0]
%timeit first_True_island_len(a)
%timeit first_true2(a)
%timeit first_True_island_len_IFELSE(a)


a = np.array([True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True])    
1000000 loops, best of 3: 353 ns per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.32 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.4 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.38 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 µs per loop

a = np.array([False] * 100000 + [True] * 10000)
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 513 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 110 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.55 µs per loop

a = np.array([False] * 100000 + [True])
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 472 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 14 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.45 µs per loop
```

Comment: You can simplify that Numba code a lot. `for x in bools: count += x; if count and not x: return count`. It's also a bit faster.

Comment: Just a note that the solution above produces non-intuitive results if the Series starts with a False. Presumably, if the Series starts with a False, then the result should be 0.

Answer (score 6):

Using NumPy funcs, one solution would be -

```
np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,s,0])))[0]
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: s
Out[16]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
dtype: bool

In [17]: np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.r_[0,s,0])))[0]
Out[17]: 3
```

For performance, we need to use `np.concatenate` in place `np.r_` and then slicing to replace the last differentiation -

```
def first_True_island_len(a): # a is NumPy array
    v = np.concatenate(([False],a,[False]))
    idx = np.flatnonzero(v[1:] != v[:-1])
    if len(idx)>0:
        return idx[1] - idx[0]
    else:
        return 0
```

Inspired by [@piRSquared's `argmax` and `argmin` trickery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612126/3293881), here's one more with a bunch of `IF-ELSE`'s -

```
def first_True_island_len_IFELSE(a): # a is NumPy array
    maxidx = a.argmax()
    pos = a[maxidx:].argmin()
    if a[maxidx]:
        if pos==0:
            return a.size - maxidx
        else:
            return pos
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this way will find the first consecutive occurrences for `True` or `False`,  and only for `True`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True],columns=["Boolean"])
df['consecutive'] = df.Boolean.groupby((df.Boolean != df.Boolean.shift()).cumsum()).transform('size')
count_true_false = df['consecutive'][df['consecutive']>1].iloc[0] # count first consecutive occurrences for True or False 
count_true = df['consecutive'][(df.Boolean == True) & (df.consecutive>1)].iloc[0] # count first consecutive occurrences for True 
print count_true_false
print count_true
```

Output:

```
3
3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
s = pd.Series([True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True])

cs = s.groupby((~s).cumsum()).agg('sum')
cs[cs > 1].iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: Just looked this question up again and found this

Comment: Clever use of groupby. So clever, I'm still trying to understand it.

Comment: @Esteban LOL... Me too.  This answer is almost three years old.

Answer (score 3):

I initally hadn't got that the question was about pandas Series. The answer below uses list methods, but is still valid if the pandas Series are converted to list (method `a.to_list()`).

Without any import, you can find the first occurrence of `False` by using the method `index` of list, and this will be the number you are looking for:

```
a = [True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True]
n_head_true = a.index(False) if False in a else len(a)
print(n_head_true)
> 3

a = [True, True, True]
n_head_true = a.index(False) if False in a else len(a)
print(n_head_true)
> 3

a = [False, True, True]
n_head_true = a.index(False) if False in a else len(a)
print(n_head_true)
> 0
```

The `if` is needed because `index` gives error if all values are True.