# Is there a simple way to find the last consecutive True value in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a small dataframe with bool values representing the ranges over which three parameters are optimum.

It looks like this in the debugger:

```
(Pdb) p insensistive_ranges.loc[-0.2:0.2]
           P      Q      n
-0.20  False   True  False
-0.16  False   True  False
-0.12   True   True  False
-0.08   True   True  False
-0.04   True  False  False
 0.00   True   True   True
 0.04  False  False   True
 0.08  False   True   True
 0.12  False   True  False
 0.16  False   True  False
```

(The optimum values are when the index == 0.00)

I want to return the index of the last consecutive True value counting up from 0.0 and also counting down from 0.0 for each parameter.  In other words, this:

```
(Pdb) p highest
P    0.00
Q    0.00
n    0.08
(Pdb) p lowest
P   -0.12
Q    0.00
n    0.00
```

The closest I have come is this, but it goes one step too far in each direction (finds the first non-True value not the last consecutive True value):

```
(Pdb) p insensistive_ranges.loc[0.0:delta].idxmin()
P    0.04
Q    0.04
n    0.12
(Pdb) p insensistive_ranges.loc[0.0:-delta:-1].idxmin()
P   -0.16
Q   -0.04
n   -0.04
```

Any ideas?

(Note that you can't start at the beginning or end of `insensistive_ranges` because there might be other True values in each series that are not consecutive starting from 0.0.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611125/pandas-count-the-first-consecutive-true-values) has some innovative solutions with numpy array methods but they look pretty complex.

Answer (score 1):

We need to create a counter for consecutive groups of True/False. Then find the maximum and minimum index for each column for the `0` group.

```
df1 = df.ne(df.shift(1)).cumsum().copy()

# Lowest
df1.eq(df1.loc[0]).idxmax()
P   -0.12
Q    0.00
n    0.00
dtype: float64

# Highest
df1.eq(df1.loc[0])[::-1].idxmax()
#P    0.00
#Q    0.00
#n    0.08
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: Nice.  Finds the max of a cumsum of ~df.  Took me a while to get my head round but that is pretty clever.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work now.  I am not getting the right results after your update.

Comment: @Bill Hmm, okay, I'll have to think about why, perhaps there wasn't a case I considered. But I'll rollback to the solution that worked.

Comment: It's still not working.  I get `0.04, 0.00, 0.00` for the first one and `-0.08, -0.04, 0.00` for the second.  Shall we roll back to the very first solution which I think did?

Comment: Wait, it looks like my data has changed so let me work on this a few mins.

Comment: @Bill yes, perhaps add a `.copy()` after defining `df1`. But let me know if `df1 = df.ne(df.shift(1)).cumsum().copy()` works for finding the highest and lowest. That's the cleanest solution I think.