# How to check if the value is between two consecutive rows in dataframe or numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I need to write a code that checks if a certain value is between 2 consecutive rows, for example:

row <50 < next row

meaning if the value is between row and its consecutive row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))
```

The output is:

```
    A
0  67
1  78
2  53
3  44
4  84
5   2
6  63
7  13
8  56
9  24
```

What I'd like to do is to check if (let's say I have a set value) "50" is between all consecutive rows.

Say, we check if 50 is between 67 and 78 and then between 78 and 53, obviously the answer is no, therefore in column B the result would be 0.

Now, if we check if 50 is between 53 and 44, then we'll get 1 in column B and we'll use cumsum() to count how many times the value of 50 is between consecutive rows in column A.

UPDATE: Let's say, if I have column C where I have 2 categories only: 1 and 2. How would I ensure that the check is performed within each of the categories separately? In other words, the check is reset once the category changes?

The desired output is:

```
    A   B   C   count
0  67   0   1    0
1  78   0   1    0
2  53   0   1    0
3  44   1   2    0
4  84   2   1    0
5   2   3   2    0
6  63   4   1    0
7  13   5   2    0
8  56   6   1    0
9  24   7   1    1
```

Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: can you provide some sample data that mimics your current problem?

Comment: @Datanovice Let's say I generated a dataframe df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))
and I want to check if 50 is between all consecutive rows (between first and second row, second and third, third and fourth, etc.).

Comment: not really following can you edit your question with indended output from the above?

Comment: `df['count'] = df.groupby(df['A'].shift().ne(50).cumsum()).cumcount()` maybe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Count the first consecutive True values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611125/pandas-count-the-first-consecutive-true-values)

Comment: Is 50 between 84 and 2?  So, your count should increment to 3 on index row 5?

Comment: @Scott Boston, you're right, but you get the idea

Comment: @joker4171 what do you think about my answer, does it fit your what your looking for?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the real data you’re working with? Is it all numeric?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @oppressionslayer! Great responses! Quick question: imagine i have another column called "C" and I need to group data by column C first and then do those calculations, how would I code it? What I'm after is to have cumsum() reset for each group.

Comment: @joker4171 cumsum auto resets for each group, check out: df.groupby('count').cumsum()  There are also more advanced usages using ne. and shift for more advanced situations, but usually there is a solution

Comment: @oppressionslayer, I think my issue is that I need to "groupby" BEFORE the rows are checked for whether or not there's 50 in between and I can't get my head around that.

Comment: If you add the second or  third column to your question, i'm sure we could figure it out

Comment: @oppressionslayer, thanks a lot for your invaluable help! I edited my question with UPDATE note.

Comment: @joker4171 can you check if your second output would look like what i put in my answer at the end?

Comment: @oppressionslayer, your example is a bit wrong because it mixes categories (1,2). For instance, at indexes 2 and 3, it's 53 and 44 in column respectively, but column C has values 1 and 2. So, column "count" at index 3 should be 0. The bottom line: the checks must be performed for 1 and 2 (under C column) separately.

Comment: @joker4171 i updated my answer to get your updated desired ouput! check it out in my answer

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
what = ((df.A < 50) | (50 > df.A.shift())) & ((df.A > 50) | (50 < df.A.shift())) 

df['count'] = what.astype(int).cumsum()                                                                                                                                                           

    A  count
0  67      0
1  78      0
2  53      0
3  44      1
4  84      2
5   2      3
6  63      4
7  13      5
8  56      6
9  24      7
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 1)), columns=list('A'))                                                                                                         
what = ((df.A < 50) | (50 > df.A.shift())) & ((df.A > 50) | (50 < df.A.shift())) 
df['count'] = what.astype(int).cumsum()                                                                                                                                                                                    

    A  count
0  45      0
1  53      1
2  44      2
3  87      3
4  47      4
5  13      4
6  20      4
7  89      5
8  81      5
9  53      5
```

Would your second output look like this:

```
df
    A  B  C
0  67  0  1
1  78  0  1
2  53  0  1
3  44  1  2
4  84  2  1
5   2  3  2
6  63  4  1
7  13  5  2
8  56  6  1
9  24  7  1

df_new = df

what = ((df_new.A < 50) | (50 > df_new.A.shift())) & ((df_new.A > 50) | (50 < df_new.A.shift())) & ((df_new.C == df_new.C.shift() ))                                                

df['count'] = what.astype(int).cumsum() 
                                                                                                                                                                                     df
```

Ouput:

```
    A  B  C  count
0  67  0  1      0
1  78  0  1      0
2  53  0  1      0
3  44  1  2      0
4  84  2  1      0
5   2  3  2      0
6  63  4  1      0
7  13  5  2      0
8  56  6  1      0
9  24  7  1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's just subtract "50" from series and check sign change:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[67,78,53,44,84,2,63,13,56,24]}, columns=list('A'))

s = df['A'] - 50
df['count'] = np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).ne(0).cumsum()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    A  count
0  67      0
1  78      0
2  53      0
3  44      1
4  84      2
5   2      3
6  63      4
7  13      5
8  56      6
9  24      7
```